# App in facebook Require Approval?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**Scenario is like this:**

1. I have created an app in facebook say myApp.
2. I have integrated facebook login in my website say mywebsite.com.
3. I am intended to fetch user's "education_history" ,"work_history" ,"books" , "music".
4. I am not asking permissions for writing anything on user's facebook wall.

**Here the problem.**

I am able to fetch required information from facebook only when I logged in ( myapp created on my account only ) but when someone else try to login to mywebsite.com through facebook then I get only his public profile nothing else.

Why is it so ? What I am missing. All permissions are correct.

Thanks for help

EDITED :

Code for login URl :

// Return facebook or linkedIn login url
public function loginurl(){

```
// It is facebook

    $login_url_params = array(

            'scope' => 'email,user_actions.book,user_actions.fitness,user_actions.music,user_actions.news,user_actions.video,user_education_history,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_website,user_work_history',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/users/store/fb/'
        );


$login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);

echo "<a href=" . $login_url.'>Login</a>';



    }
```

Comment: what permissions are you using exactly?

Comment: 'scope' => 'email,user_actions.book,user_actions.fitness,user_actions.music,user_actions.news,user_actions.video,user_education_history,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_website,user_work_history',

Comment: @luschn : As of now I am testing on localhost , so callback is http://localhost/getfbData/ .. Can it cause a problem ?

Comment: localhost will cause a problem wince FB will redirect you to your domain after login

Comment: No it is not that problem .. Only think is that I am able to fetchmy data but when my friend logged in to mywebsite.com through facebook then He get facebook permission box asking only for public profile and email .

Comment: @PalDev: _“localhost will cause a problem wince FB will redirect you to your domain after login”_ – that is not a problem, because it is the _browser_ that follows the redirect.

Comment: @CBroe : Just for fetching education_history and work_history , Facebook will review my app even when user get prompted that myApp is going to fetch data .. :(

Comment: Anyway, to your question - you need to go through their approval process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a warning when you authorize some specific permissions as App Admin/Developer, telling you to review them:

> Apps requesting more than public_profile, email and the user_friends permission must be reviewed by Facebook before those permissions can be requested from people

Here´s more information about the review process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Localhost will only work for you, but not for other users. Except you are trying with another user on your computer, of course.

Comment: Yes When I login then I get box like "myApp" want to fetch this and that information .. But when my friend logins then facebook pop say "myApp want to fetch your public profile and email". It does not ask for all permissions that I have mentioned

Comment: exactly, because those other permissions need to get reviewed first